# mongoose: save if not exists, won't update if exist

Tags: mongoose

In mongoose, is there one line code that can save the document if it does not exist otherwise DON'T update the existing one.

I have searched online but most of the answers are about updating on the existing one document.

Comment: you can check if the document exist, create it if not. why do you want one line ?

Answer (score 7):

After some lucky search, I found the following links which are really helpful:

- [MongoDB atomic “findOrCreate”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358857/mongodb-atomic-findorcreate-findone-insert-if-nonexistent-but-do-not-update)
- [Mongodb how to insert ONLY if does not exists (no update if exist)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48220677/mongodb-how-to-insert-only-if-does-not-exists-no-update-if-exist)
- [Mongoose: atomic FindOne-Or-Insert(), do not update existing instance if found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211567/mongoose-atomic-findone-or-insert-do-not-update-existing-instance-if-found)
- [How to create item if not exists and return an error if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011091/how-to-create-item-if-not-exists-and-return-an-error-if-exists)

The key is to set `$setOnInsert` in update params, and `upsert:true` in options params.

Here is a code example:

```js
let query = {id: searchId};
let update = { 
  $setOnInsert: {
    id: searchId,
    foo: foo,
    bar: bar,
  }
};
  
let options = { upsert: true };
SampleModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options)
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Any thoughts or answers or improvements are definitely welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Note that this only works for an array!

Even though this is an old post, I found something that could help people coming across this.

Instead of using the $setOnInsert, you can use $addToSet. This will add whatever data you are inserting but if the data exists, then nothing will happen.

```js
let query = {id: searchId};
let update = { 
  $addtoSet: {
    [id: searchId]
  }
};
  
SampleModel.findOneAndUpdate(query, update)
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```