# Add multiple records without overwriting or updating existing ones in a MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a .csv file containing 1.7 million records. Some of these records are already in my database collection (2.2 million records), others are not. I want to add the records which are not yet in the collection without overwriting or updating the existing records. Each record has an enterprise number as unique property.

So far I could only found solutions which are first creating all the operations and than use the `model.bulkWrite()` method to perform these operations. Since these operations use `updateOne()` the already existing records will be updated.

So I'm looking for a way to add new records in bulk without updating or overwriting existing records.

**Code**

```
// Read data
const data = await readCSV('data/companies.csv');

// Format data
const formatted_data = data.map(record => ({
    name: record.name,
    enterprise_number: record.enterprise_number,
    vat_number: record.vat_number,
    legal_form: record.juridical_form || null,
    activity_codes: (!record.nace_codes || record.nace_codes === '') ? [] : JSON.parse(record.nace_codes.replace(/'/g, '"')),
    address: {
        street: record.street,
        house_number: record.house_number,
        additional: record.additional,
        postal_code: record.postal_code,
        city: record.city,
        country: record.country
    },
    phone: record.tel || null,
    mobile: record.mobile || null,
    email: record.email || null,
    establishment_date: record.start_date,
    status: record.is_active === '1' ? 'active' : 'inactive',
}));

const batchSize = 10000;
    
// Create batches of 10.000 records
for (let i = 0; i < formatted_data.length; i += batchSize) {
    let batch = formatted_data.slice(i, i + batchSize);

    let operations = batch.map((row) => ({
        updateOne: {
            filter: { enterprise_number: row.enterprise_number },
            update: row,
            upsert: true
        }
    }));

    try {
        let result = await Company.bulkWrite(operations);
        
        console.log(`Batch ${i} done: ${result.modifiedCount} records modified, ${result.upsertedCount} records upserted`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error updating batch ${i}: ${error}`);
    }
}

console.log('All done');
```

Based on the answer of @Fraction which was a link to this topic [Mongodb how to insert ONLY if does not exists (no update if exist)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48220677/mongodb-how-to-insert-only-if-does-not-exists-no-update-if-exist) I updated my code to the following

```
for (let i = 0; i < formatted_data.length; i += batch_size) {
    let batch = formatted_data.slice(i, i + batch_size);

    let operations = batch.map((row) => ({
        updateOne: {
            filter: { enterprise_number: row.enterprise_number },
            update: { $setOnInsert: row },
            upsert: true
        }
    }));

    try {
        let result = await Kbo.bulkWrite(operations);
        console.log(`Batch ${i} done: ${result.result.nUpserted} records inserted`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error inserting batch ${i}: ${error}`);
    }
}
```

This is kind of working. It's upserting new records and it does not update the properties of a existing record BUT it's updating the `updated_at` property of all matching records.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongodb how to insert ONLY if does not exists (no update if exist)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48220677/mongodb-how-to-insert-only-if-does-not-exists-no-update-if-exist)

Comment: @Fraction I tried the solution in that question and it's weird. The properties of the matching record are not updating but the updated_at property is updating to the current timestamp. Also the result response of the `bulkWrite` method contains a field with the number of modified rows and every row has been modified. To keep the data correct, the updated_at property may not be updated for existing records.

Comment: Why do you re-invent the wheel? Have a look at [mongoimport](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/), it provides `--mode=<insert|upsert|merge|delete>`

Comment: @Thore see this [comment](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6861#issuecomment-414118221), you can try to set [`timestamps`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) to `false` and add `created_at` manually

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `--mode=upsert` will replace existing documents

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Because mongoimport is not able to format the code and I don't want to create another script to format the code